# How can we update existing partition data in aws glue table without running crawler?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

When we are updating data in existing partition by using manual upload to s3 bucket then the data is showing in existing partition in athena glue table.

But when data is updated by using API, the data uploaded to s3 bucket is in existing partition, but in glue table data is stored in the different partition which is current date[last modified] (August 2, 2022, 17:52:15 (UTC+05:30)),

[image]

but in my s3 bucket partition date is different(s3://aiq-grey-s3-sink-created-at-partition/topics/core.Test.s3/2022/07/19/) which is 2022/07/19 this.

so when I check same object in glue table I want the partition by this date 2022/07/19.

but it shows the partition by current date without running crawler.

When I run crawler it writes data in correct partition,

[image]

but I don't want to run crawler every single time.

**How can I update data in existing partition on glue table by using API ?
Am I missing some configuration that is needed to achieve required result for this process ?
Please suggest if anybody has Idea on this.**

Comment: How are you updating the partition details now? Which API and code/snippet used to update? Add it to your question.

Comment: You might use [UpdatePartition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_UpdatePartition.html) Glue Web API with your preferred programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Here're two solutions I proposed:

- use boto3 to run an Athena query to alter partition: [ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html)

```
    athena = boto3.client('athena')
    response = athena.start_query_execution(
        QueryString='ALTER TABLE table ADD PARTITION ... LOCATION ... ', // compose the query as you need
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': database
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    )
```

- use boto3 to create partition via glue data catalog: [glue.Client.create_partition(**kwargs)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_partition)